# Change option text to value jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a list of options, and what I'm trying to do is replace the text of the selected option with the value of the current option.

```
<select name="sorting-box" class="sort-box" id="sort">
        <option value="Alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="Math: &uarr; to &darr;">Math Required: High to Low</option>
    <option value="Math: &darr; to &uarr;">Math Required: Low to High</option>
            <option value="Lang: &uarr; to &darr;">Second Language Required: High to Low</option>
    <option value="Lang: &darr; to &uarr;">Second Language Required: Low to High</option>
    <option value="Salary: &uarr; to &darr;">Average Starting Salary: High to Low</option>
    <option value="Salary: &darr; to &uarr;">Average Starting Salary: Low to High</option>
        <option value="Credits: &uarr; to &darr;">Credits Required: High to Low</option>
    <option value="Credits: &darr; to &uarr;">Credits Required: Low to High</option>
</select>

$('#sort').change(function(){
        $(this).find('option:selected').text($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Eq2A/

It's similar to this, but I can't determine how to make it switch back if it's not selected, so it leaves it the way it was.

I was thinking maybe add a class, and detect on the class? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I really can't tell what you're trying to do.  Do you realize that `$("#sort").value()` is the value that is selected in the dropdown?

Comment: Instead of doing all that, why not just add a textbox or a label, and populate the label with the selected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3Eq2A/2/)**

```
$('#sort option').each(function () {
    $(this).data('txt', $(this).text());
});
$('#sort').change(function () {
    $('option', this).each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).data('txt'));
    });
    $(this).find('option:selected').text($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: This would likely be the most simple answer I've seen. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @tuffkid had almost exactly the same thing, except the extra data-field with data. I was going with simplicity in mind. Adding an extra field without using jquery to do is more complex to me. :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data attribute to store the state of the text and then restore it if another option is chosen. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Eq2A/3/

---

code for demo

html same as above

js

```
$('#sort').change(function(){
 var $prev = $('.tempSelect',this);
 if( $prev.length > 0 ){
  $prev.text($prev[0].getAttribute("data-text"));
  $prev[0].removeAttribute("data-text");
  $prev.removeClass('tempSelect');
 }
 var $sel = $(this).find('option:selected');
 $sel.addClass("tempSelect");
 $sel[0].setAttribute("data-text",$sel.text());
 $sel.text($sel.attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: @stepquick - It is faster than the others. Perhaps that requires two extra lines of code. Perhaps performance isn't an issue with this small example, but if there are enough options it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Just store original text in option attribute:

```
<option value="Math: &uarr; to &darr;" data-original="Math Required: High to Low">Math Required: High to Low</option>
```

and than you can easily achieve what you want:

```
$('#sort').change(function() {
    $(this).find('option').each(function() { $(this).text($(this).attr('data-original')); });
    $(this).find('option:selected').text($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: This works the way I was thinking. Thank you, but there was a better answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping value with a class as identifier.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JFB4H/1/

Full code below,

```
$('#sort').change(function () {   

    $(this).find('.swapped').text(function (i, v) {
        tmp = v;
        return this.value;
    }).val(function () {
        return tmp;
    }).removeClass('swapped');

    var tmp = $(this).val();
    $(this).find('option:selected')
        .val(function () {
        return this.text;
    }).text(tmp)
        .addClass('swapped');

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add data attribute "data-text" to your "option" elements, and reset the text on change. Add something like this to your "change" handler:

```
$("#sort").change(function(){
    var $swapped = $(this).find(".swapped");
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");

    $swapped.text($swapped.data("text")).removeClass("swapped");

    $selected.text($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')).addClass("swapped");
});
```

Comment: I only wanted it to switch for the currently selected option. Not all of them.

Comment: When you get to the "change" handler, your "current" option isn't current anymore - it's your previous "current", so you don't know which one was your previous "current" that you replaced. So, with this you'd reset all of them, and then make the switch for the new "current". If I'm making any sense ;) Perhaps adding a class to the "current" would enable you to easily select it back.

Comment: I edited the original answer to include "flagging" swapped optino element.